# SOAP Exception while invoking the service through proxy

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, java-metro-framework

We are trying to call a SOAPService. But this call, sometimes works and sometimes it doesn't work. There is no definite pattern when it doesn't work. The following is what we get when it doesn't work. We are using Oracle Metro stack.

Any idea why is it not working and what could be the error.

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException while invoking FetchDiagnosticEvent over SSP... 
com.sun.xml.ws.server.UnsupportedMediaException: Unsupported Content-Type:     soap-env/xml;charset=utf-8 Supported ones are: [text/xml]
at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:299)
at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:133)
at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:358)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(HttpTransportPipe.java:269)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:218)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:137)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:110)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:641)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:600)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:585)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:482)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:323)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:161)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:113)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:93)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:144)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.fetchDiagnosticEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.apple.ist.applecare.adr_integration.invoker.FetchDiagnosticEventApiInvoker.invokeApiOverSSPAndGenerateResponse(FetchDiagnosticEventApiInvoker.java:184)
at com.apple.ist.applecare.adr_integration.invoker.FetchDiagnosticEventApiInvoker.invokeApi(FetchDiagnosticEventApiInvoker.java:99)
at com.apple.ist.applecare.adr_integration.ADRIntegrationManager.fetchDiagnosticEvent(ADRIntegrationManager.java:204)
at com.apple.ist.applecare.adr_integration.test.FetchDiagnosticEventTest.invokeApi(FetchDiagnosticEventTest.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is at java or soap adapter which is calling  webservice. 
Have you heared of module parameter conversion? You need to remove soap envelop before calling webservice.

I dont know exactly what is your scenario but hope you can do this,

Before calling webservice,
Remove soap envelop of your request message.
Is there any class which can perform content conversion to plaint text/xml.

OR

You can also configure your third party tool which is handling webservice to receive both format with soap envelop and as well as in plain text format. Then you wont get this error.

What is happeing here, Your proxy is sending request message wrapped in soap envelop while your third party tool which is receiving your request is not expecting it within soap envelop may be it is wrapping soap envelop at their end.

Regards,
ambuj

Comment: @Ambuj, thanks for your answer. If that is the case, then all the call should fail. Why some of the call fails? And moreover, when I take that same SOAP request and execute it through SOAPUI, it works fine, all the time.

Comment: Hey Philipp, Actually I have faced this issue earlier. Could you please post one success request message and one fail request message here.